# Make 2 viewports depending on each other - libgdx

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, resize, viewport

I have a rather easy question I think.

I am having 2 FitViewports, if I resize my game, both Viewports are resized.
This is working out great:

1. [When I resize my window (smaller).](https://gyazo.com/d9d011c83bbb4dd3259ebe28d5f4ac57)
2. [But this happens when im resizing it to be bigger.](https://gyazo.com/a16f9581190e0f1dd833c08e080ddfcf)

As you can see the white background is the right size, the square in the middle is also- but I want it to be just as wide as the white background.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    backViewport.update(width, height); //white background
    gameViewport.update(width, height); //square

}
```

I want the program to do so:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    backViewport.update(width, height); //white background
    gameViewport.update(backViewport.getWidth(), backViewport.getWidth());

}
```

Getting the new background width-size and setting my gameViewport to the same.
I will do both width- and height- .getWidth(), because I want it to be square.

This is not working because it is stretching my square in the y-axis.

Thanks for your time and hopefully somebody knows a solution.

EDIT: By doing this,

```
gameViewport.setScreenSize(backViewport.getScreenWidth(), backViewport.getScreenWidth());
```

I achieved to get the square the right size, but I still cant figure out, how to move it back to the center of the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the wiki, take a look once more.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

You have one square viewport and one rectangle viewport. Your viewports are working as expected, they are trying to fit to the screen. You are experiencing a *problem* because they have different sizes.

I don't think you want to use 2 separate viewports if they are going to act same. Instead use one viewport and draw like;

```
draw(x, y + bottomPadding)
```

when drawing your game.